# Referencing another class within a class for json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

In my service class constructor I populate two repositories:

```
private List<BackupRule> rules;
private List<BackupPath> paths;

public RuleService()
{
  List<BackupRule> _rules = new List<BackupRule>();
  List<BackupPath> _paths = new List<BackupPath>();
  using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
  {
    string json = wc.DownloadString(jsonRuleFile);
    if (json.Length > 0)
    {
      _rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BackupRule>>(json);
      _paths = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BackupPath>>(json);
    }
  }
  rules = _rules;
  paths = _paths;
}
```

Then I try to create a rule and add the rule to the repository:

*code to create the rules*

```
IRuleService db = new RuleService();
List<BackupPath> paths = new List<BackupPath>();
paths.Add(new BackupPath { Type = PathType.Source, Value = "C:\\Test\\" });
paths.Add(new BackupPath { Type = PathType.Destination, Value = "C:\\Test\\" });
paths.Add(new BackupPath { Type = PathType.Source, Value = "C:\\Test\\" });
paths.Add(new BackupPath { Type = PathType.Source, Value = "C:\\Test\\" });
BackupRule rule1 = new BackupRule() { Name = "test1", Type = RuleType.Archive, UserName = System.Environment.UserName, Paths = paths, EndOfDay = true, Created = DateTime.Now};
BackupRule rule2 = new BackupRule() { Name = "test2", Type = RuleType.Archive, UserName = System.Environment.UserName, Paths = paths, EndOfDay = true, Created = DateTime.Now };
db.CreateRule(rule1);
db.CreateRule(rule2);
db.SaveChanges();
```

*Interface Methods that add the rules to the repositories*

```
public BackupRule CreateRule(BackupRule rule)
{
  if (rules.Any(r => r.Name == rule.Name))
  {
    return null;
  }
  rule.Paths = rule.Paths.OrderBy(p => p.Type.GetHashCode()).ToList();
  foreach (BackupPath path in rule.Paths)
  {
    path.Id = (paths.Count() == 0) ? 1 : paths.LastOrDefault().Id + 1;
    paths.Add(path);
  }
  rule.Id = (rules.Count() == 0) ? 1 : rules.LastOrDefault().Id + 1;
  rules.Add(rule);
  rules = rules.OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();
  return rule;
}
```

*Interface Method that serializes (sic?) back to json*

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
  using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@jsonRuleFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
  using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
  {
    jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, rules);
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, paths);
  }
}
```

*json output*

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "test1",
    "UserName": "Aaron",
    "rule_type": "Archive",
    "Paths": [
      {
        "$id": "1",
        "Id": 5,
        "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
        "Type": "Source"
      },
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "Id": 6,
        "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
        "Type": "Source"
      },
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "Id": 7,
        "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
        "Type": "Source"
      },
      {
        "$id": "4",
        "Id": 8,
        "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
        "Type": "Destination"
      }
    ],
    "EndOfDay": true,
    "Created": "2014-07-12T20:14:03.9126784-05:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "test2",
    "UserName": "Aaron",
    "rule_type": "Archive",
    "Paths": [
      {
        "$ref": "1"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "2"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "3"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "4"
      }
    ],
    "EndOfDay": true,
    "Created": "2014-07-12T20:14:03.9126784-05:00"
  }
][
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 8,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Destination"
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 7,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Source"
  },
  {
    "Id": 8,
    "Value": "C:\\Test\\",
    "Type": "Destination"
  }
]
```

*Classes being serialized*

```
// using statements added to post to help 
// reader understand I am using Json.Net
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class BackupRule
{
  [JsonProperty]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rule_type")]
  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
  public RuleType Type { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty(ItemIsReference = true)]
  public List<BackupPath> Paths { get; set; }
  public bool EndOfDay { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
public class BackupPath
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
  public PathType Type { get; set; }
}
```

The problem(s) is the json isn't even a proper format it gives me:

> Warning    1   Only one top-level array or object is allowed in a JSON document.

And it doesn't actually reference the serialized `BackupPath` class it just references other `BackupPaths` created in other `BackupRule` objects.  Where did I go wrong here? Ideally I would like it to create two "tables" out of the lists and have the `BackupRule` reference the `BackupPaths` "table" much like it does in the second `BackupRule` example but instead of `BackupRule` #2 referencing `BackupPath` stored in `BackupRule` #1 I'd rather both reference the serialized `BackupPath` "table". Also ideally i'd like to store both of the serialized lists in one json file, but I am flexible on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the warning, that's because you have this:

```
serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, rules);
serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, paths);
```

As the warning says, JSON really can only have 1 top level element and you have written 2 top level elements.  To make the warning go away, you could wrap `rules` and `paths` into a single object:

`serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, new {Rules = rules, Paths = paths});`

Comment: This actually solved the problem entirely.  As long as I serialize Paths first, The Rules reference the paths: `serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, new {Paths = paths, Rules = rules});` Going to wait to see if someone else answers with a slightly more stable/efficient solution before I mark yours as the answer.